# Why pie chart not getting displayed?

Tags: java, android

The pie chart is not displaying in the following code. The screen is blank.
I dont get any error in the code.

```
public class PieGraphOnExpensesForAGivenDateRange extends Activity {
    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {
        int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Pie Graph");
        int k = 0;
        for (int value : values) {
            series.add("Section" + ++k, value);
        }
        int[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN};
        DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
        for (int color : colors) {
            SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            r.setColor(color);
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, series, renderer, "Pie");
        return intent;
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you step through the code?

Comment: do you have internet permission in your manifest ? BTW your using any chart libraries

Comment: When I step through the code, it is not entering public intent..method. The code goes to instrumentation.java and then the screen becomes blank.

Comment: I dont jave internet permission in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Following program is working fine for me.

```
private void openChart(){
 
        // Pie Chart Section Names
        String[] code = new String[] {
            "Eclair & Older", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb",
            "IceCream Sandwich", "Jelly Bean"
        };
 
        // Pie Chart Section Value
        double[] distribution = { 3.9, 12.9, 55.8, 1.9, 23.7, 1.8 } ;
 
        // Color of each Pie Chart Sections
        int[] colors = { Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.RED,
                        Color.YELLOW };
 
        // Instantiating CategorySeries to plot Pie Chart
        CategorySeries distributionSeries = new CategorySeries(" Android version distribution as on October 1, 2012");
        for(int i=0 ;i < distribution.length;i++){
            // Adding a slice with its values and name to the Pie Chart
            distributionSeries.add(code[i], distribution[i]);
        }
 
        // Instantiating a renderer for the Pie Chart
        DefaultRenderer defaultRenderer  = new DefaultRenderer();
        for(int i = 0 ;i<distribution.length;i++){
            SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            seriesRenderer.setColor(colors[i]);
            seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
            // Adding a renderer for a slice
            defaultRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
        }
 
        defaultRenderer.setChartTitle("Android version distribution as on October 1, 2012 ");
        defaultRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        defaultRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
 
        // Creating an intent to plot bar chart using dataset and multipleRenderer
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(getBaseContext(), distributionSeries , defaultRenderer, "AChartEnginePieChartDemo");
 
        // Start Activity
        startActivity(intent);
 
    }
```

Hope it helps.